# Delete Post but retain image of post [WP REST API]

Tags: posts, rest-api, media

Currently, when I delete a post in my wordpress website, the image is deleted automatically.

Which is fine for most cases, however, there are certain posts where I don't want to delete the image from the database such as a post that has the plain website logo (default background image when subscribers don't post image). In such case, how can I delete the post while keeping the image.

I'am using the wordpress rest api and issuing the following request (in python) to delete the post.

```
url='https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
post_id=22334

r = requests.delete(url + '/' + str(post_id) + '?force=True')
```

Any suggestions?

Possible solution routes:

-Is there a way to mark/protect an image from auto deletion when post is deleted

-Is there a way to instruct wordpress not to delete featured media when deleting the post

This is the deleteimage function used by the custom theme when a post is deleted:

```
public function deleteImages(Post $post)
{
    foreach (themeApp('gallery_fields') as $galleryField) {
        /* @var GalleryField $galleryField */
        foreach ($galleryField->getValue($post) as $imageId) {

            wp_delete_attachment($imageId);
        }
    }
}
```

RESOLVED:
Issue was due to custom theme not designed/configured properly. Hence I modified the deleteImages function in the theme files to check if image is used more than once (if used once delete image, if more than once then dont delete image):

```
public function deleteImages(Post $post){
foreach (themeApp('gallery_fields') as $galleryField) {
    /* @var GalleryField $galleryField */
    foreach ($galleryField->getValue($post) as $imageId) {


        $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'fields'=>'ids');
        $array2 = get_posts( $args );

        foreach($array2 as $item){
            $images = get_post_meta( $item,'customfield_19213');#this is the custom field corresponding to image id

            $imagelist[]=$images;
        }

        foreach ($imagelist as $img){foreach ($img as $im){
            $imageflattened[]=$im;
        }
        }
        $imageflattened=array_count_values($imageflattened);
        $ImageID=strval($imageId);
        $count= $imageflattened[$ImageID];

        if ($count==1){ wp_delete_attachment($imageId);}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "when I delete a post in my wordpress website, the image is deleted automatically" - if by "the image", you meant the featured image, then that would not happen by default, i.e. the post is deleted, but the featured image (the image file) is not deleted.

Comment: So maybe there's a plugin which is deleting the attachment and the image file itself? And if so, then you should check the plugin's documentation or ask on their support forums for assistance.

Comment: Ya i meant the featured image. Yes it shouldnt do that by default, but i cross checked again and it is doing that. Ill check regarding plugins

Comment: You can try deactivating all plugins for a while and see if that image is still being deleted. But have you checked the Media Library - is the image really not there anymore? How did you confirm/know the image was deleted?

Comment: There are my plugins: WP migration
Contact Form 7
Elementor
Mailchimp
Nginx Cache

Comment: I have deactivated everything else. I can tell its deleted because its no longer in the api response of wp-json/wp/v2/media and also because posts using the same image no longer display an image

Comment: Iam using a custom theme so it have to do with that.?

Comment: Could be. You can confirm by switching to 2021 or any other default/core theme, then see if the same issue persists.

Comment: I have added the imagedelete function in OP. Ill try adding a check to ensure image is not used elsewhere prior deletion. Let me know in case you have any advise. thanks 8-)

Comment: If you just want to check if the current image/attachment ID is set as the post's featured image, then you can use something like `if ( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) !== (int) $imageId ) { wp_delete_attachment($imageId); }`, assuming `$post` is an object and that `$post->ID` is set. As for the "elsewhere" - "check to ensure image is not used elsewhere prior deletion" - that won't be an easy task since the image could be linked to from other posts, e.g. using the URL in an `img` tag.

Comment: It didnt work. Issue was resolved by changing deleteImages function (in original post) such that we check how many times image is used by existing post. If used once, delete. otherwise, we keep.

Comment: I included the code in OP in case useful

Comment: I just wanted to say that your code could be made much simpler.. e.g. use `'fields' => 'ids'` to get just the post IDs, e.g. using `get_posts()` - `$array2 = get_posts( array( 'fields' => 'ids', ... ) );` - that way, you wouldn't need the `$the_query` and `$arrayxy` parts.

Comment: Thanks Sally. I have simplified the solution accordingly.

Comment: I appreciated your efforts, but actually, I believe the `$imageflattened` could be defined and filled outside the first `foreach`. And I thought, you might want to give [this gist](https://gist.github.com/5ally/2afd2a35d45083b338a2f7ed4eb441e7) a try? (feel free to comment on that gist, if you want to) And my last note here would be, that you should always define variables before using them, e.g. `$imagelist = array(); foreach(...){ ... $imagelist[]=$images; }`, i.e. define `$imagelist` before adding items to that array. Have a nice weekend and happy coding!